# Google Colaboratoryでのデバッグのやり方

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratoryでのデバッグ、ステップインなどのやり方がわかりません。
PyCharmのように、ブレイクポイントを作ったり、F8でステップインはできないのでしょうか。
常識的な内容なのか、検索してもヒットしません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

通常 Google Colaboratory や（その元となっている）Jupyter Notebook では、セルを分けることによって実行を途中で止めることができます。自分の体感的には、セル単位で止めつつ必要に応じて `print` すれば事足りる場面が多いです。

しかしそれでもデバッガーが欲しくなる場合があるかもしれません。ここではふたつのやり方を紹介します。

### `%debug` magic

Jupyter (IPython) には組み込みで [`%debug`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-debug) というマジックコマンドがあり、これを利用することができます。`%debug` は Python 標準のデバッグツールである [pdb](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pdb.html) を Jupyter 上で起動してくれます。`%debug` には引数ありで使う場合と引数なしで使う場合があるのですが、私が便利だと思っているのは引数なしで使うものです。これは、何かしらエラーが出たあと、次のセルに `%debug` と打ち込むとエラーが出た時点のスタックフレームからデバッガーを起動してくれます。

使えるコマンドは標準の pdb と同じものです：https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

とりあえずは以下が分かれば基本的な操作ができると思います。

- `h [command]`：ヘルプを出す
- `p [expression]`：式を評価して出力する
- `n`：次の行へ
- `c`：次のブレークポイントへ
- `q`：その場で終了する

実行例です：

```
def harmonic(n):
  acc = 0
  for i in range(n):
    acc += 1.0 / i
  return acc
print(harmonic(10))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fc532000561a> in <module>()
      4     acc += 1.0 / i
      5   return acc
----> 6 print(harmonic(10))

<ipython-input-5-fc532000561a> in harmonic(n)
      2   acc = 0
      3   for i in range(n):
----> 4     acc += 1.0 / i
      5   return acc
      6 print(harmonic(10))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

```
%debug
```

```
> <ipython-input-5-fc532000561a>(4)harmonic()
      2   acc = 0
      3   for i in range(n):
----> 4     acc += 1.0 / i
      5   return acc
      6 print(harmonic(10))

ipdb> p acc
0
ipdb> p i
0
ipdb> q
```

更に [`%pdb`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pdb) を使うと、エラーが起きたところで自動的に（`%debug` を打ち込まずに）pdb が起動するよう設定することもできます。

### `Pdb().set_trace()`

また、もう少し手作業で、[`IPython.core.debugger.Pdb`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html#IPython.core.debugger.Pdb) を使うことによってブレイクポイントを作ることができます。ブレイクポイントを置きたい行に次のプログラムを挿入します。

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()
```

するとプログラムがこの行に到達した際に pdb の REPL が起動し、コマンドを打ち込みながらデバッグできます。

具体例です：

```
def harmonic(n):
  acc = 0
  for i in range(n):
    from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()
    acc += 1.0 / i
  return acc
print(harmonic(10))
```

```
> <ipython-input-8-8f37e64adc73>(5)harmonic()
      3   for i in range(n):
      4     from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()
----> 5     acc += 1.0 / i
      6   return acc
      7 print(harmonic(10))

ipdb> p acc
0
ipdb> p i
0
ipdb> c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8f37e64adc73> in <module>()
      5     acc += 1.0 / i
      6   return acc
----> 7 print(harmonic(10))

<ipython-input-8-8f37e64adc73> in harmonic(n)
      3   for i in range(n):
      4     from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; Pdb().set_trace()
----> 5     acc += 1.0 / i
      6   return acc
      7 print(harmonic(10))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```